# Return vector element reference by [] operator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class or struct, lets say, *Container*, with the following structure:

```
template <typename type> struct Container {
    vector <type *> v;
    ...
    functions
    ...
    type* operator[] (int i) { // not sure about this
          return (v)[i];
    }
};
```

where type can be a standard type or a custom defined class or struct.

This struct is supposed to work like this:

```
Container<type> * c(10);
c->function(); // calls a function that iterates over the elements of v
```

If I want to access individual elements of the vector, I can call

```
c->v[0]->function()
```

where function is a member of the *type* class;
This works like expected; however, it could be simplified to

```
c[0]->function()
```

since the [] operator, as defined by me, *would* return a pointer to the contained class and not the container itself, but the compiler still complains that the container class has no member called "function".
This is not a big issue, as can be easily avoided with a different syntax, but makes me think that I have some fundamental misunderstanding on how pointers and references works.
What would be a proper way to define the [] operator here and what am I missing?
Thank you in advance

EDIT: I edited the question to reflect my actual code

Comment: It should work. Can you show the code that makes compiler complain about `c[0]->function()`?

Comment: c[0]->function(). Does 'type' have a function named function()? If it doesn't, then compiler is doing it's job.

Comment: Yes. The compiler tells me that Container has no member function, not type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator[]` seems to be fine. You do seem to be missing a semi-colon after the name your struct.

> > Yes. The compiler tells me that Container has no member function, not type.

Did you define a function for `Container` then?

Here is a compiling, working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    void Function () {
        std::cout << "A::Function()" "\n" ;
    }
};

template <typename type> struct Container {
    std::vector <type *> v;

    void Function () {
        std::cout << "Container::Function ()" "\n" ;
    }

    type* operator[] (int i) { 
          return (v)[i];
    }
};

int main (void)
{
    A a ;

    Container <A> c ;

    c.Function () ;

    c.v.push_back (&a) ;
    c[0]->Function () ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

> > Container::Function ()
> >     A::Function()

**Update**

Here's an example of using a pointer.

```
int main (void)
{
    A a ;

    Container <A> *pC = new Container <A> ;

    pC->Function () ;

    pC->v.push_back (&a) ;
    (*pC) [0]->Function () ;

    delete pC ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Of course, you should never have to use a raw pointer like this. You could use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) instead or you can wrap your memory into a class for [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii).

Comment: Thank you. Your code works perfectly and made me notice that the compiler complains only if I initialize a pointer to Container.
Container<A> c works, but Container *<a> c does not. I still do not understand why this happens.

Comment: @user3556781 Take a look at the update in my answer. The output is the same.

Comment: Just perfect. I'll also follow your advice and start with smart pointers. Thank you

Comment: @user3556781 - Please note that your operator []  will not work if the object is const.  You need a second overload of operator [] to work on const objects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good point, I meant to link [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) somewhere in my answer, but forgot to.